# How to pass secrets as environment variables into a Docker Github Action?

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions

In my workflow I'm running a custom action using the following step:

```yaml
- name: Run action
  uses: ./backend
  env:
    MY_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
```

And here's `action.yml`:

```
name: "Backend"
on: [pull_request]
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: "Dockerfile"
```

For some reason, `MY_SECRET` is empty in my `Dockerfile`. I tried accessing it both in a shell script file and the `RUN` command:

```
RUN echo "MY_SECRET: $MY_SECRET"
```

But it's always empty.

I tried both repository-level and organization-level secrets, but the environment variable is always empty.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `$MY_SECRET` inside the container. Instead, you should pass argument through the `--build-arg` flag.

I think you should do something like:

```
steps:
  - run: docker build --build-arg MY_SECRET=$MY_SECRET .
```

And then you'll be able to access `MY_SECRET` in the build phase.

If you're building using an action and not manually, you should find out how to pass the build arguments.

Comment: Thanks! Found the following in the docs: `To access the environment variable in a Docker container action, you must pass the input using the args keyword in the action metadata file. For more information about the action metadata file for Docker container actions, see "Creating a Docker container action."`

Comment: @Tzach Great. So I believe that will do it.